# Defining Monad Operators

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell's Monads, I can easily define the operator `(>=>)` as :

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g
```

I also know that `(>>=)` can be expressed using `(>=>)`: Let's call `(>>=)` as `(..)`:

```
(..) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
m .. k = m >=> \_ -> k
```

However something is not right ... could someone point what?

Comment: That is possibly just a copy-paste mistake, but you used the `(>=>)` signature for your `(>>=)`.

Comment: @duplode Isn't it the correct thing? I'm creating an alias for `(>>=)`  as `(..)`, so I want to apply the `(>=>)` operator to define `(..)` ... makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense; it is just that the type of `(>>=)` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, while in your question you wrote `(..) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)`.

Comment: You have an extra problem here that no one has mentioned yet: You *cannot* define a `(..)` operator, because `..` is reserved syntax, used in range notation.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen you can call it the `foobar` operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea of using a constant function (that is, `\_ -> -- etc.`) to make a function out of the argument which isn't a function so that you can pass it to `(>=>)` is sound. There are just two issues. Firstly, you are doing it to the wrong argument, as the one which isn't a function is `m`:

```
GHCi> :t \m k -> (\_ -> m) >=> k
\m k -> (\_ -> m) >=> k :: Monad m => m b -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

Secondly, `(>=>)` gives you a function (of type `a -> m c` in the demo just above). You have to apply it to something to get a result type that matches the one of `(>>=)`. As that argument is irrelevant (you are ultimately feeding it to a constant function) you can just use `()`:

```
GHCi> :t \m k -> ((\_ -> m) >=> k) ()
\m k -> ((\_ -> m) >=> k) () :: Monad m => m b -> (b -> m c) -> m c
```

And that's it. I find it slightly prettier to use the `const` function rather than writing `\_ ->`, and so I would write it as:

```
(>>..) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
m >>.. k = (const m >=> k) ()
```

Comment: Methinks the choice of `()` is particularly apt, and the reason for that is made clearer by replacing `const m` with `\() -> m`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the following:

```
(..) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
m .. k =
  (const m >=> k) undefined
```

Using `const` we're lifting an operation of type `m a` to `whatever -> m a`. This lifted version does not give a damn, what we pass to it so it might as well be the `undefined`.

Comment: I'd put it the other way: so it might as well *not* be `undefined`. duplode's choice of `()` seems eminently reasonable. In fact, `()` makes special sense because `(->) ()` can be read as "point".